# Constraint warnings with status bas hidden

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have an app where the status bar is hidden. I am setting some constraints against the safe area top since I want it to handle the iPhone X. The problem is that interface builder want me to place the object 20 px down. I.e. if I place a label at y=0 and set a constraint that the distance to the top should be 0, I get a warning about a "Misplaced view, expected = 20, actual = 0".

It is not a huge problem since the layout works fine in practice on all kinds of devices. But it means that I have 50+ warnings when I build, which is pretty annoying and risk to obscure more important messages. Is there a way to get rid of these warnings? It doesn't seem to be a way to tell interface builder that there is no status bar.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you upload a screenshot?

Comment: Added screenshot

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is set the constraint at 0 to the `Safe Area`(y:20),  but in your storyboard you have positioned the label at 0  to the `Superview`(y:0). Upon built as you have removed the status bar the safe area becomes the top of the view hence you see the label at y:0.

So what it is telling you is "Hey, you have asked me to be at 20 but here you have positioned me at 0" your layout works because upon build the constraints are taking over. If you just click on the triangle and then update frames everything will be fine.

Comment: No, it won't be fine since updating it will move the label to y=20 when it should be at y=0. Since there is no status bar it should not be moved 20 px down.

Comment: Can you show me your constrains? Also clarify a few things for me, "It is not a huge problem since the layout works fine in practice" are you saying that the label appears 0 top from the Superview? and if so which device are you testing?

Comment: It works fine on all devices from iPhone 4s to iPhone X, both in the simulator and on real devices. I have added a screen shot. The problems is that it doesn't seem to be a way to tell interface builder that there is no status bar.

Comment: As i suggested update frames and it WILL be fine! You are not moving the label to y:20, you have it 0 to the safe area that happens to be y:20, upon build that your status bar goes, your label constraint is still the same 0 to the safe area its just now happens to be y:0. Makes sense?

Comment: No it doesn't make sense. I can choose from having the label in the wrong position (y=20) in interface builder, or have it in the right position and get a warning. None are OK, but I prefer the warning since I using IB as a layout tool.

Comment: Again, by placing it in y:20 is NOT(bold,italic,underlined) in the wrong position-this is not your constraint, 0 from the top(safe area) is, and because on storyboard you have the status bar(thats your safe area there) it is placed at 20, upon build status bar is removed and safe area becomes the beginning of your view at y:0! An exaggerated example would be if you had 5 status bars and you placed the constraint 0 top to the safe area, the label would be at y:100.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173135/discussion-between-do2-and-sten).